# creating an object on every click

Tags: android, arrays, oop, button

is there a way to create an object every time the user clicks on a certain button ?

i made an array of objects to act as a container for the objects created
but the program crashes !!
is there a working way ?

```
package com.fawzyx.movie_rental_store;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.String;

public class MemReg_activity extends Activity{

    public member[] member ;


    String name; 
    String id ;
    String mail;
    String ccard ;
    String address ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reg_layout);
        final EditText etname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etname);
        EditText etmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etmail);
        EditText etid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etid);
        EditText etccard=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etccard);
        EditText etaddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etadress);


        name = etname.getText().toString();
        id = etid.getText().toString();
        mail = etmail.getText().toString();
        ccard = etccard.getText().toString();
        address = etaddress.getText().toString();

        Button btSubmit= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btsubmit);

        btSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if (etname.getText().toString().length()<5)
            {
            Toast.makeText(MemReg_activity.this, "Enter a valid name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
            }   
            else 
            {
                int x=0;
                x++ ;
                member[x]  = new member(name, id, mail , ccard , address);

            }
            }
        });



    }

}
```

Comment: You're adding your new object to an array that you never initialized. That will result in a null pointer exception. You should use a list if you want to have an expanding set of objects.

Comment: @dymmeh 
how to make a list ?

Comment: List<Member> memberList = new ArrayList<Member>(); put this is onCreate and then onClick you can do memberList.add(your object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

member is not initialized in anywhere.

```
//initialize
member = new member[15]; // 15 is just an example.
```

On the other hand, if the size is not fixed, you should consider using `List` instead.

```
List<member> members = new ArrayList<member>();
```

and in onclick method,

```
members.add(new member());
```

And to access the items,

```
member m = members.get(0); // first item in the list
```

To iterate all items,

```
   for(member m : members){
      // m is your member object
   }
```

Comment: is there a way to access and search this list ?

Comment: sorry i meant searching by one of the objects attributes

Comment: If the object attribute is unique, you can use HashMap<K,V> or you need to iterate through arraylist and compare